# consuming webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, consuming

http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/webservicecallfromandroid/
The above link taught me how to consume webservice in android its working properly,the problem is it just printing some text after loading.But i need to consume the webservices using buttons while clicking.Please let me know the codes or with some example codes.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with webservice consumption at all.

You need to implement OnClick on the button then have it call a function to runs that code.

```
private void consumeWS(){    
    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty(“i”, 5);
        request.addProperty(“j”, 15);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnSubmit: consumeWS(); break;
        }
    }
```